# What exactly is weird about waves propagating without a medium? What does it violate?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, waves, history, aether

I can not seem to grasp, why exactly does light travelling through space without the need of any medium was baffling for the scientists of 1800's.

Comment: Because most of other non-EM type waves needs medium to propagate, like mechanical waves, pressure waves, etc ?

Comment: What is waving if there is no medium?

Comment: what do you mean @AndrewSteane ?

Comment: technically a vacuum is not “nothing” but is made of fields. No “physical” medium may be a more accurate way to ask.

Comment: I wonder if [hsm.se] might be more appropriate for such a question, as the answer almost certainly would require a historical perspective.

Comment: It was already baffling to 17th century scientist and inventor Christiaan Huygens.

Answer (score 3):

If you are used to waves traveling down a string, the wave is a traveling sideways deflection of the string. For sound waves, it is a traveling compression of the air.

In the 1800's, waves were mechanical. If something was a traveling deflection of the medium, there must be a medium to deflect.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the famous Cheshire cat from Alice in Wonderland. It periodically disappears so that only its grin is still visible. A wave without a medium is like such a grin without a face. Note that also quantum mechanical waves have no medium.

Answer (score 1):

A water wave, or a wave on a string served as a mental model to describe the behavior of light. The mental model was needed because the actual propagation could not be directly seen or physically perceived (as sound waves could).

Until the mathematical description of this mental model became sufficient, the physical sense of the model was all that one had to go by. The physical sense suggests that a wave moves by periodically disturbing a medium (water, string, air). Without such a medium, it isn't trivial to understand what is being disturbed and therefore how a wave can propagate.